# Any way to record Amazon Connect Contact Flow with Lex interaction?

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have a working Lex bot inside a Contact Flow to prompt the caller with a series of questions. We have a requirement to have the entire interaction audio recorded. Per the documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-up-recordings.html, the recording does not start until after an agent (a.k.a. the softphone) answers the call. Since we're not using a softphone, is there any other alternative to getting a full recording of the Contact Flow interaction with Lex?

I see that the contact flow has logging and Lex has Conversation Logs where parts of the interaction are stored in separate objects and audio files, however, per our requirements we must have a single audio recording of the entire interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is stitching the recordings from the Lex Conversation logs and the call recording together after the fact.

It looks like the recordings of the Lex utterances are stored in folder with the ContactID of the call as part of the object name. For example...

aws/lex/BOTID/ALIASID/VERSION/LANGUAGE/9c8b2dd7-736c-4b41-9d80-df6d774f4538/2943f259-fa34-4ccd-9128-03bccbeff0e3-ut-0.wav

and that first guid is the contactid for the call.

So you could have a lambda triggered on the Connect call recordings s3 bucket that then searches for the utterance wav files based on the contactid and then combines them with the actual callrecording.

Not ideal, but I don't think there is a simple solution.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned this. I thought of this method, as well. Unfortunately, I don't think this will be valid for us, but this at least validates my understanding and thought process. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to setup a contact flow that uses the Start Media Streaming with Lambda involved. The process uses Kinesis and then you can retrieve the full transcript through your S3 (or send it whereever you need).  Although doesn't give you direct steps, this link explains the use.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/use-media-streams-blocks.html